# Problem of ambiguous character format using scale_x_date in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

```
str(tidy_factors)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   70650 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ date    : Date, format: "1992-06-01" "1992-06-02" ...
     $ Factor  : Factor w/ 5 levels "CMA","HML","MKT",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ Variable: Factor w/ 2 levels "Centrality","Return": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ Value   : num  -0.0012 -0.0022 -0.0012 -0.0029 0.0003 -0.0043 -0.0037 -0.0038 0.0026 -0.0024 ...
```

I would like to understand the pattern in the `Value` that the `Factor` takes over time (`date`).

```
library(tidyverse)    
tidy_factors %>% filter(Variable=="Centrality")%>%
group_by(date) %>%  
ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Factor, fill=Value))+
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

I get to visualize it in a nice manner but the dates on the x axis are indistinguishable. When I try to `scale_x_date` to get a better understanding of the values that it takes according to different periods I get the following error:

```
tidy_factors %>% filter(Variable=="Centrality")%>%
  group_by(date) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Factor, fill=Value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels="%Y")

Error in charToDate(x) :
    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I also tried "1 years","1 month" ecc...
The dates are already unique for each `Factor` level. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Just a dummy suggestion, removing `group_by(date)` does it change something ? Right now, I do not see any error in your code. Can you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is that it is plotting a separate bar for every date, and then labelling the plot with every date.  You want a plot that treats the date as a continuous variable, e.g. maybe a `geom_segment` from (x, y) to (x, y+1).

Comment: geom_bar used in that way seems the best solution for my plot. Isn't there any other way to change the breaks in x?